# Change DispatchTimers to other timer to solve performance issues. Cannot update UI, program shutting down

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, dispatcher

**EDIT #1**: I have placed worker.RunWorkerAsync() within my timer loop and my application does not shut down anymore. Although nothing seems to happen now.

For performance reasons i need to replace DispatcherTimers with a other timer that runs in a different thread. There are to much delays / freezes so DispatcherTimer is no longer a option.

*I am having problems to actually update my GUI thread, my application always seems to shut down without any warnings / errors.*
I have mainly been trying to experiment with BackGroundWorker in attempt to solve my problem. Everything results in a shut down of my application when i launch it.

Some code examples would be greatly apperciated.

**Old code dispatcher code:**

```
    public void InitializeDispatcherTimerWeging()
    {
        timerWegingen = new DispatcherTimer();
        timerWegingen.Tick += new EventHandler(timerWegingen_Tick);
        timerWegingen.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, Convert.ToInt16(minKorteStilstand));
        timerWegingen.Start();
    }

    private void timerWegingen_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayWegingInfo();
        CaculateTimeBetweenWegingen();
    }
```

Every 5 seconds the DisplayWegingInfo() and Calculate method should be called upon.

The GUI updates happen in the Calculate method. There a button gets created **dynamically** and added to a observerableCollection.

**Button creation (short version):**

```
    public void CreateRegistrationButton()
    {
        InitializeDispatcherTimerStilstand();

        RegistrationButton btn = new RegistrationButton(GlobalObservableCol.regBtns.Count.ToString());
        btn.RegistrationCount = GlobalObservableCol.regBtnCount;
        btn.Title = "btnRegistration" + GlobalObservableCol.regBtnCount;
        btn.BeginStilstand = btn.Time;

        GlobalObservableCol.regBtns.Add(btn);
        GlobalObservableCol.regBtnCount++;

        btn.DuurStilstand = String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", 0, 0, 0);         
    }
```

**New code using threading timer that runs in a different thread then the GUI**

```
    public void InitializeDispatcherTimerWeging()
    {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        TimerCallback callback = MyTimerCallBack;
        timerWegingen = new Timer(callback);

        timerWegingen.Change(0, 5000);
    }


    private void MyTimerCallBack(object state)
    {
        DisplayWegingInfo();
        CaculateTimeBetweenWegingen();
    }
```

I timer runs in a separate thread then the GUI thread (that dispatcherTimer uses). But i cannot seem to be able to send this update to the UI thread itself so the updates get actually implemented in the UI.

*The button gets refilled with new values every 1 sec trough a other timer. "DuurStilstand" is a dependency property*

```
    private void FillDuurStilstandRegistrationBtn()
    {
        TimeSpan tsSec = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds);
        TimeSpan tsMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(stopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes);
        TimeSpan tsHour = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(stopWatch.Elapsed.Hours);

        if (GlobalObservableCol.regBtns.Count >= 1
                    && GlobalObservableCol.regBtns[GlobalObservableCol.regBtns.Count - 1].StopWatchActive == true)
        {
            GlobalObservableCol.regBtns[GlobalObservableCol.regBtns.Count - 1].DuurStilstand =
                            String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", tsHour.Hours, tsMin.Minutes, tsSec.Seconds);
        }
    }
```

Would i need to use the invoke from Dispatcher in the above method? If so how exactly?

Not sure how to call the ui thread after initializing the doWork method of the BackGroundWorker, my application keeps shutting down after right after start up.
I have tried using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in several methods but all failed so far. At the moment i have no clue how to implement it.

All the above code is written in a separate c# class.

Best Regards,
Jackz

Comment: You can't update UI from a worker thread or timer callback.  Dispatcher.Begin/Invoke is required.  Which makes your UI code work *exactly* like a DispatcherTimer, just with a lot more ways to shoot your foot.  Whatever *other* code is making the UI thread slow to respond needs to be moved to a worker thread.

Comment: Can you illustrate with some code if that would be possible? I have tried with invoke without any succes.

Comment: There's nothing to demonstrate, your original solution with DispatcherTimer is best.  Why your UI is unresponsive is unguessable from the question.  Use a profiler if you can't figure out why.

Comment: It performs a query every 5 seconds to a db which takes like 1 second to execute in SQL management studio. Also a stopwatch is used to record the downtime. The application slows down when this gets performed. For example i have a clock that runs fine, but gets freezes when performing the other two timers... So it seems dispatchertimer is not a option and gives to much delay. Regards jackz.

Comment: Eggzactly, you want to run the *query* on a worker thread.  *That's* the slow code.

Comment: I have read when using the threading timer its already running on a separate timer then the UI thread? Or do you mean something different altogether and i am doing it totally wrong? At the moment i am still clueless for quite some time trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran my sample of your code, the DisplayWegingInfo() was throwing an exception trying to access UI components.  We need to call Invoke() from the Timer thread to update the UI.  See DisplayWegingInfo() below.  Note: this assumes that CaculateTimeBetweenWegingen() does not interact with the UI.

```
   void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        TimerCallback callback = MyTimerCallBack;
        timerWegingen = new System.Threading.Timer(callback);
        timerWegingen.Change(0, 3000);

    }

    private void MyTimerCallBack(object state)
    {
        DisplayWegingInfo();
        CaculateTimeBetweenWegingen();
    }

    private void DisplayWegingInfo()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(DisplayWegingInfo));
            return;
        }

        // at this point, we are on the UI thread, and can update the GUI elements
        this.label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    private void CaculateTimeBetweenWegingen()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: CalculateBetweenWegingen does interfact with the UI. It basically calculates the downtime between the dates received from the DB query (DisplayWegingInfo). When the downtime is large enough a button gets dynamically created. DisplayWegingInfo only performs a query and adds that result to a list, it does not interact with the UI. I cannot access this.InvokeRequired, how come??  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Jackz Oh, right - you are doing the work in another class.  In that case, you need a reference to the form or the form's WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.

Comment: I cannot seem access .InvokeREquired i'm afraid.

Comment: @Jackz - Agree w/ Hans comment above.  You want to move the query to the BG worker, and then update the UI afterwards.  When you need to interact with the UI, you will need to use Form.Invoke() on your form.